The intuition behind the differential/pushforward
First, I apologize for any english mistakes, it's not my first language and it has been  while since the last time that I needed to write in english.
To get on the core of my question, lets recap the some basic concepts of smooth manifolds. Suppose $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds, and $f\colon M\to N$ is a differentiable function, i.e. for any given local charts $x\colon U\subset M\to\mathbb{R}^m$ and $y\colon V\subset N\to\mathbb{R}^n$, the composition map $y\circ f\circ x^{-1}$ is differentiable. The tangent spaces $T_pM$ and $T_qN$, where $q = f(p)$, are thought to be the best linear approximation of the manifold locally. Then, any differentiable function induces a linear map $f_*\vert_p\colon T_pM\to T_qN$, which we call the differential, or the pushforward, at $p$, by the expression $f_*\vert_p(v)(g) = v(g\circ f)$, where $v\in T_pM$ and $g\colon N\to\mathbb{R}$. My question is: If we express the tangent vectors at $p$ and $q$ by an basis induced by local charts, then the differential is basically the derivative, but there is another way to justify that the differential is indeed the best approximation of $f$ by a linear map? Because $f_*\vert_p$ is, in summary, an natural linear map, maybe the most obvious linear map, induced by $f$, but this is enough to justify our intuitive notion of what the differential is?

Maybe not enough for a whole answer, but the tangent space at any point is in a sense the best local approximation of a smooth manifold as a vector space, so the induced linear map is naturally the best linear approximation of $f$ at this point in my opinion. This is a little bit hard to answer though, because it is just intuition and there is not really a rigorous definition of "best linear approximaiton"

You can also do this for maps of submanifolds of $R^n$.

That the differential of $f$ is the best linear approximation of $f$ makes sense only if $f$ is a map from an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, because a rigorous statement of this requires rescaling the domain and codomain. There's no co-ordinate-free way to rescale a manifold.
I like to think of the differential of $f: M \rightarrow N$ as encoding all possible directional derivatives of $f$ in the following sense:
Given a vector $v \in T_pM$, there is a curve $c: I \rightarrow M$ such that $c(0) = p$ and $c'(0)=v$. Composing this with $f$, you get a curve in $N$,
$$ f\circ c: I \rightarrow N. $$
The pushforward of $v$ by $f$ is defined to be velocity vector of this curve at $t=0$,
$$ f_*v = (f\circ c)'(0). $$
